# Ext-JS Form TextArea Validation Q

Tags: javascript, validation, extjs, dom-events

I've implemented some validation in my form by extending the `form.VTypes` class to include another vtype that I personally made.  However I am unsure if this is the best path to go, for starters I want to control when the validation happens (onBlur).  I want to also display a checkmark when it is valid and have the submit value be disabled until the form is filled out correctly.

I've been digging around to see how the Ext-JS API textfield's validator attribute works, but I can't find a good example of it.  Does the `validateOnBlur` work using it? I'm trying to see how all these different validation attributes / methods are supposed to work together.  I don't know what I am supposed to call what when.

---

EDIT**
I have it set now so that the send button is only enabled after it runs `isValid(false)` on each textfield.  Apparently this works for both my VType validation and my allowBlank:false I set.  However I do not understand how to execute another method when its actually valid... I saw the valid public event, but I was unsure when I could call it (an example would be awesome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that can get most of what you want done without much effort is using `monitorValid: true` on the `Ext.form.FormPanel`, and adding `formbind: true` to the form's buttons.

```
new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    monitorValid: true,
    items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            allowBlank: false
            ...
        }, {
            xtype: 'textarea',
            vtype: 'customvtype'
        }],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Submit',
        formbind: true
    }]
});
```

When using `monitorValid`, the form will also fire a `clientValidation` event that you can use to listen for other actions to perform when the form becomes valid.

Comment: hey thanks, sorry for the late accept.  I actually got it working on my end utilizing the listeners: attribute and the public events invalid and valid.